# JS CSOM to redirect to another SharePoint URL

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, application-pages, redirect

I have an application page which takes some inputs for list creation. Based on these inputs, i am using JavaScript Client Object model to create a new list.
Once the list is created a notification message is displayed. **Is it possible to redirect to another SharePoint page using  JavaScript CSOM** (after the notification is displayed) ?

*Update*
: I tried with window.location.href and the redirection is working fine. I am wondering if the same can be done using JS CSOM.

```
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(Message,false);
window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=redirectionURL;},5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built in function in SharePoint for detecting it, like a callback or something. But you could maybe do it with `DOMNodeRemoved`

PS: Browser support for that event im not sure about, you'll have to check that out if users have older browser.

```
function AddNotification() {
   var notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Message", false);

   $(document).bind("DOMNodeRemoved", function(e)
    {
        if(e.target.id == notifyId) 
        { 
               // Add redirect script here
            alert("Removed: " + e.target.id); 
        }  
    });

}

AddNotification();
```

I'm not sure what you mean abut JSOM redirect, because in the end its the same it does as location.href more or less. But there is a built in "redirect" function:

[SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.navigateTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659680%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

It usese the `STSNavigate` function from sp.core.js:

```
function STSNavigate(Url)
{ULSxSy:;
    if (window.location.search.indexOf("IsDlg=1") !=-1)
    {
        if (Url.indexOf("?") !=-1)
        {
            if (Url.match("&$") !="&")
            {
                Url=Url+"&IsDlg=1";
            }
            else
            {
                Url=Url+"IsDlg=1";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Url=Url+"?IsDlg=1";
        }
    }
    if (isPortalTemplatePage(Url))
        window.top.location=STSPageUrlValidation(Url);
    else
        window.location=STSPageUrlValidation(Url);
}
```

As you can see, its just does some checks, and then set `window.location`

Comment: Thanks for the help. SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.navigateTo(url); worked too. +1 for the details. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is relevant, but I had done something very similar. I had used SP.UI.ModalDialog. You can add options to it and can have a callback fuction that triggers whenever events occour(eg. dialog is closed). You can have the code for redirecting in this callback function.

http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-redirect-reload-or-refresh-a-page-after-closing-the-SharePoint-2013-Modal-Popup-Dialog might help

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks. Window.location.href works. But i was wondering if there is any option available through JS CSOM ?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement, like you want to send data present in the source page to the destination link?